# memcache php doesn't expire

Tags: php, memcached

I'm truing to use memcache in my PHP code:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('10.0.0.21', 11244) or die ("Could not connect");
$store = 10; # in seconds
$cache_key = "Counter";

$counter = $memcache->get($cache_key);
if (empty($counter))
{
    $counter = $this->getTotal();
    $result = $memcache->replace($cache_key, $counter); 
    if($result == false) 
    { 
        $memcache->set($cache_key, $counter, 0, $store);
    }
}

echo $counter;
```

What happens is that value doesn't update. It staid the same for like days - much longer that 10 sec expiration time I set in the code.
What am I doing wrong? My understanding that key will be removed after 10 sec but looks like it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only set the expiration time if the key is not already present. You need to set it in the call to [`replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.replace.php), too:

```
$result = $memcache->replace($cache_key, $counter, 0, $store);
```

should fix your problem.